# Cross compiler libntoh for arm-linux

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compiler for Arm-Linux [libntoh library](https://github.com/sch3m4/libntoh) with my gcc cross compiler for ARM-LINUX

Now this project used cmake , How to convert it to ARM-LINUX ?

Comment: 1. Browse the project to detect which tools and buils systems are used to build the project. 2. Learn the tools that are used to build that project (cmake and shell scripts) 3. Learn the tools even better for yourself and future projects 4. Configure the project to use the crosscompiler 5. Compile. | The question "How can I do it?" is I think close to too broad for stackoverflow - with what exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have edit the post , and will thank for your help